# how to create something that is similar to this picture?

Tags: formatting, draw

I'd like to create something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX40G.jpg) and have no idea how to even start.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Here's a start, read chapter 2-5 of [the TikZ manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) to get an introduction to TikZ: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{tikz} \begin{document} \begin{tikzpicture} \node [scale=12] {\textbf{9}}; \node at (0,1.5) {an}; \end{tikzpicture}  \end{document}`

Comment: Please embed pictures in your post to make it easier and faster for others to decide if it is worth their time.

Answer (score 3):

A solution with the  `\psDefBoxNodes` from `pst-node`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{erewhon, cabin}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
\bfseries
\psscalebox{20}{\psDefBoxNodes{Neun}{\sffamily9}}
\uput[u](Neun:tC){\color{green}auf}
\uput{6ex}[u](Neun:tC){\color{magenta}über}
\uput{8ex}[d](Neun:bC){\color{cyan}unter}
\uput{6ex}[u](Neun:C){\color{red}in}
\uput{4ex}[u](Neun:Cl){\color{lightgray}an}
\uput{10.5ex}[145](Neun:Cl){\color{pink}vor}
\pnode[-2ex, 6ex](Neun:Cr){T}
\uput{2ex}[15](T){\color{olive}hinter}
\rput[bl]{-90}(T){\color{orange}neben}
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]